# Visual Code equivalent of FileSync extension for Sublime Text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an extension for Visual Studio Code that has the same functionality as FileSync on Sublime Text? Specifically I'm looking for something that can just copy files over the network, no sftp/ftp needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None existed so I made my own [File Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CatStarwind.filesync).